# How do I turn on/off my discord bot worker on heroku using Discord command?

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a discord bot deployed to Heroku and I don't want to open the heroku website every time in order to turn on/off my discord bot from the worker tray. Is there a way to control my discord bot from discord commands using another managing bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your managing bot to use and make calls to the [Heroku Platform API's](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference).
Particularly, the [Dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno) section specifies how you can Create, Restart and Stop your Dynos by making API calls by passing in your App ID/Name and Dyno ID/Name.